# How can I disable the event sounds in Kubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu, sound-theme

I really don't like the sounds which Kubuntu plays during startup, or during thinks like moving a file to Trash. How can I disable all such notification sounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go to Application and System Notifications in System Settings and select Player Settings tabs marking No audio output:

[image: snapshot6]

Comment: No, don't do this. It disables ALL SOUNDS, not just the startup sound.

Comment: In my case that disables nothing

Answer (score 5):

KDE Userbase: http://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Application_and_System_Notifications

> Manage Notifications
>
> Some applications and subsystems of your workspace can notify you
>   about various events. Here you can specify which events you wish to be
>   notified about, and how you want to be notified.

System Settings > Application and System Notifications > Manage Notifications.

Pick the application. The KDE Workspace has the trash, logout, login etc notifications.

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm!