# Kubuntu is doing weird sound even after reboot every 15 seconds or so

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I rebooted, then closed every program I could think of and I still hear repeating after around 15 seconds:

[Here's what it sounds like.](https://soundcloud.com/trufavarela/annying-sound-thats-going-to-kill-me) (Minus the static, that's just the recording)

Is there any way of knowing which program is doing which sounds, or any sound at all? How do I start debugging this?

Comment: Seriously, it's going to drive me nuts.

Comment: may be a alert sound - http://askubuntu.com/questions/101554/how-can-i-disable-the-event-sounds-in-kubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell over the static but for me it sounds like one of the default [pidgin](https://pidgin.im/) sounds.

It could also be the [systembell](http://www.kubuntu.org/docs/kquickguide/C/ch03s07.html#sound-systembell).

To Further debug you sound you could kill the existing pulseaudio server, with `pulseaudio -k`. And launch
 `pulseaudio -vvvvv`

It could be that you have any kind of IM running in background? Is there anything visible running in your [messagetray](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-notifications.html.en)?

Comment: Oh god, thank you!! Pidgin was running with nothing in the system tray!!